# Ionic: Big textarea slips under nav-bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I have a big textarea (height 75% of screen-height). When I click into the textarea in order to input some text, the keyboard slides out and the textarea slips under the nav-bar (please have a look at the image).

What can I do in order to prevent this behaviour?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: you might need to set `margin-top` on the `textarea` which will be equal to the height of the nav bar.

Comment: @RohitKumar Thanks. I already tried that (even with padding-bottom for ion-content), but that does not work.

Comment: did you set `margin-top` in percentage??

Comment: @RohitKumar No, with fixed height of 40px